# Overlapping matplot Bar Graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm learning matplot in python and I want to make a bar graph with side-by-side bars. My plot is currently overlapping for some reason.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yamzb.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_groups = 7
means_frank = (82, 75, 86, 63, 90, 73 ,88)
means_alex = (91, 92, 80, 73, 83, 91, 71)
means_joe = (72, 42, 50, 33, 63, 34, 54)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.27
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = ax.bar(index,means_frank,bar_width,color='b', label="Frank")

rects2 = ax.bar(index,means_alex,bar_width,color='g', label="Alex")

rects3 = ax.bar(index,means_joe,bar_width,color='r', label="Joe")

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Test Scores')
plt.xticks([0, 5, 6], ["Assignments -->", "<-- Midterm", "Final"])
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

How can I make these 3 different plots appear side by side instead of overlapped?

Thanks!

Comment: Check https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: That was it! It's the first argument in the bar function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ImportanceofBeingErnest helped with this link:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

The index argument must be modified to prevent overlap.